# multiple pages link active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of pages and I want class active change when I switch pages

```
<nav class="main-navi">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="homeLink" href="index.html">
                    Home
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li >
                <a id="portfolioLink" href="portfolio_masonry.html">
                    Portfolio
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li >
                <a href="about.html">
                    About
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="active" href="service.html">
                    services
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="blog.html">
                    Blog
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.html">
                    contacts
                    <span class="dot"></span>
                    <span class="corner"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I know it will require  javascript but I'm so newbie about javascript, can you guys help me? and doest every pages have that script?

Comment: You are going to have to write that script yourself.  I would spend some time, looking at jQuery and some jQuery recipes (small bits of code designed for a specific goal - like yours), and see how close they get you.  From there- start tinkering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// grab all elements with the classes dot and corner
var all = document.getElementsByClassName(dot, corner);

// if the url contains any of the below then we set the classname of dot and corner
var contains = "example"
var contains2 = "example2"
var contains3 = "example3"
var contains4 = "example4"

function setclassname() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(contains || contains2 || contains3 || contains4) > -1) {
         // change newclassname to your preferred classname.
        all.className = newclassname;
    }
}
```

Add a onclick to your spans, include the .js file in your html pages and change the variables. (read the comments I placed)

Answer (score 0):

Each page only has the scripts that you put on it. I would recommend taking the script and making it its own script/file which you could then include on all pages.

You can get the url of the current page using `window.location.href`. Then you could write some logic to add an `active` class or something to whichever element in the list matches the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Bootstrap to build a navigation bar. It will style `<li>` elements with the `active` class. Include this in the head of your HTML file:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Here's a demo bootstrap navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
     </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

[codepen.io/anon/pen/KVbOvo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVbOvo)

[www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)